# JPA - update before remove in one transaction not working

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have 2 tables in database:

- ads - represent user defined advertisements
- ad_categories - represent categories for advertisements

every advertisement must belong to exactly one category, so in ads table I defined a foreign key pointing to ad_categories with ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION.

In my application, user must be able to delete any category, but if that category contains advertisements, they must be moved to another category before category is deleted.

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
// get currentNode
AdCategories currentNode = em.find(AdCategories.class, currentNodeId);
// get ads
List<Ads> resultList = em.createQuery("SELECT a from Ads a WHERE a.adCategoryId = :categoryId").setParameter("categoryId", currentNode).getResultList();
// get their new location
AdCategories newLocation = em.find(AdCategories.class, newLocationId);
// set their new location
for(Ads a: resultList)
    a.setAdCategoryId(newLocation);
em.remove(currentNode);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I expected, that affected advertisements will have ad_category_id changed and then the empty category will be removed. But affected advertisements are deleted too!!

I enabled logging in EclipseLink to FINEST level and found out, that when transaction is commited, firstly, UPDATE query is sent to database, which changes ad_category_id for affected advertisements and then category is deleted, but delete is cascaed to advertisements! I dont understand why, because advertisements should have updated ad_category_ids before remove occours.

I know, one simple workaround is to call `em.flush()` before removing the category, but I dont think it is optimal solution. I think, I need to understand this behaviour.

I am using EclipseLink with NetBeans and PostgreSQL.

Table definitions:

**AdCategories**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ad_categories")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findByParentId", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.parentId = :parentId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findByCategoryOrder", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.categoryOrder = :categoryOrder"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findByCategoryDepth", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.categoryDepth = :categoryDepth"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findByName", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findByGrandParentId", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.grandParentId = :grandParentId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findByParentName", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.parentName = :parentName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AdCategories.findByGrandParentName", query = "SELECT a FROM AdCategories a WHERE a.grandParentName = :grandParentName")})
public class AdCategories implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "adCategoryId")
private Collection<Ads> adsCollection;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "parent_id")
private int parentId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "category_order")
private short categoryOrder;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "category_depth")
private short categoryDepth;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "grand_parent_id")
private Integer grandParentId;
@Column(name = "parent_name")
private String parentName;
@Column(name = "grand_parent_name")
private String grandParentName;
...
```

**Ads**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ads")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Ads.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Ads a"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Ads.findByAdId", query = "SELECT a FROM Ads a WHERE a.adId = :adId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Ads.findByName", query = "SELECT a FROM Ads a WHERE a.name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Ads.findByDescriptionShort", query = "SELECT a FROM Ads a WHERE a.descriptionShort = :descriptionShort"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Ads.findByDescriptionLong", query = "SELECT a FROM Ads a WHERE a.descriptionLong = :descriptionLong")})
public class Ads implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ad_id")
private Integer adId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "description_short")
private String descriptionShort;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "description_long")
private String descriptionLong;
@JoinColumn(name = "ad_category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private AdCategories adCategoryId;
...
```

Comment: Did you by chance define a relationship from ad category back to ads, with a cascade type including DELETE or ALL? If so the provider will actually delete the ads manually (circumventing your foreign key guard at the db level). Please include in your question, the definitions for both classes (most important thing is to see the fields and JPA annotations).

Comment: yes, you are right, there is cascade type ALL. table definitions are auto generated by netbeans, so I didnt care much about them. But, even if there is cascade ALL, why it is cascading, if the rows are updated before delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you defined a bi-directional relationship, which needs to be manually managed (The JPA provider will not do it for you). In your calling code, you break the link between ads and their category, from the point of view of the ads.

```
for(Ads a: resultList)
    a.setAdCategoryId(newLocation);
```

But, your category is still holding on to a collection of ads that it believes its related too, and when you delete it, those ads get deleted as well (because of the CascadeType.ALL annotation). There are two ways you can go about fixing this.

#### Keep the bidirectional relationship

If you really need to, you can leave the relationship bidirectional, but then you would have to properly disassociate the relationship on both sides, when you want to break it. It's normal to manage the relationship entirely from the 'owning' side, so I would do something like this:

```
public class Ads implements Serializable {
    public void setAdCategoryId(AdCategories category) {
        this.category.removeAd(this);
        this.category = category;
        this.category.addAd(this);
    }
}
```

*Very rough pseudocode, you will need to flesh it out*

#### Remove the birectional relationship

Does a category really need to maintain a list of all ads that use it? Conceptually, I don't think it should. The list will get very large over time, and you could always query for it dynamically instead of storing it with each category. But that's a decision you have to make from a business point of view.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a cascade of type REMOVE (or ALL) on the collection of ads in `AdCategory`, you tell JPA: when I call `remove()` on an `AdCategory`, also call `remove()` on all the ads in this collection. So that's what JPA does.

You have a bidirectional association, it's your responsibility to make sure both sides of the association are in a coherent state. So if you change the category of an ad, you should also remove this ad from the set of ads in its category, and you should also add the ad to its new category. It's not absolutely mandatory in all the cases, but in yours, it is.

Also, your naming is really bad. An instance of `AdCategories` is a *single* category. So the entity should be named `AdCategory`. Same for `Ads`, which should be named `Ad`. The field `adCategoryId` doesn't contain a category ID, but a category. It should be named `adCategory` of `category` and not `adCategoryId`. Why name the field `adId`? It's the ID in the class Ad, so it's already obviously the ID of an Ad. It should thus be named `id`. `descriptionLong` should be named `longDescription`. That might seem like details, but those are the details that make code look good and be readable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is also helpful. my naming: entity classes are auto-generated with netbeans and form database's point of view, table names are in plural (they holds many rows), thats why names are not single. is there any easy way how to convert it?